# Install 1Password on Ubuntu 17.04 using Wine

Tags: windows, wine, 17.04, winetricks

I am trying to install 1Password on Ubuntu 17.04 using Wine, although installation appears to complete program doesn't launch.

If I use Wine Control I can see in console following error:

```
fixme:mscoree:parse_supported_runtime sku=L".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" not implemented
Unhandled loader error: 8, (null) PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (null)
err:mscoree:expect_no_runtimes Process exited with a Mono runtime loaded.
```

I did install mono-complete, and not sure how to proceed next, doesn't want to make a total mess. I tried to install NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1 via winetricks, however, it was complaining about using 64bit version.

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11950

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `Mono` for `Wine` which is independent of mono-complete package. I tried to install 1Password and for me installer starts under `Wine 2.0`. I remember dowloading `wine-mono-4.7.0.msi` from [WineHQ](http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.0/) and installing it using:

```
wine msiexec /i /home/piotr/downloads/wine-mono-4.7.0.msi
```

If you are running 64 bit version of Wine (which is default in 64bit systems) you need to run 32 bit version of Wine. Rename the wine prefix:

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.wineOld
```

Create new 32 bit prefix:

```
WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
```

and then you should be able to install `wine-mono`. I think at the moment it is not possible to install `.net` in 64 bit version of Wine. If all works well you may want to delete the old `.wineOld` prefix (unless you have some important applications/data in the old Wine).

Comment: when I try to install wine-mono I get following error: `fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet` wine version: 2.0.1

Comment: Do you run wine as root maybe? If yes - you should not run it as root.

Comment: No, I don't, I followed only instruction on the page...

Comment: Can you provide result of `winetricks list-installed`? I have the following packages installed on my `wine`: `colorprofile, consolas,corefonts,dotnet11, dotnet11sp1,dotnet20, mshflxgd, tahoma,
vcrun2003,vcrun2010`

Comment: I get following info:  `ou are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages.  If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20170327-next - sha256sum: c27f14651a9e0c3fb1d8b9dfd18777cccabe3b37d19553e200b4cf7bc90fcaa2 with wine-2.0.1 and WINEARCH=win64
20170327
colorprofile
consolas
corefonts
`

Comment: I edited my answer with instruction how to run 32 bit Wine. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57827/discussion-between-tahtisilma-and-thefullresolution).